# Is the googletest appropriate for checking performance of modules?

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm developing some library in cpp.
Now, I want to do unittest to check whether each module provides a correct result given a paritcular input.

I'm wondering whether I should use Google Test to see the performance of each module.
Is googletest capable to find hotspot in a moule (or in a library)?
Is googletest capable to show us accurate execution time?

Thank you.

Comment: no. you might want to check [libbenchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark) (by google). for finding "hotspots" you need a real profiler.

Comment: Unit testing is not performance testing. Unit testing is intended to prove correctness of execution but tells you nothing about the the speed or efficiency of the tested routine.